как сделать переменные для каждого юзера отдельными в телеграм боте на python aiogram
Я уже писал один раз бота при помощи telebot. Это был тестовый бот для просмотра школьного расписания. Проблема заключается вот в чем: Как раз при выборе просмотра расписания для определенного класса для начала необходимо было выбрать день, на который нужно посмотреть расписание, потом выбрать сам класс, и только потом уже отображается нужное расписание. Так вот, дело в том, что все эти данные для вывода расписания сохранялись в обычные переменные, и к примеру, если два юзера будут одновременно смотреть расписание, то к примеру класс первого юзера заменится классом другого юзера, который выбрал класс позже, и по итогу отобразится расписание второго юзера. Сейчас я хочу написать новый бот, уже используя aiogram. Я уже знаю про бд (в прошлый раз я не создавал бд), просто скажите мне, как вот эти вот промежуточные действия выбора чего либо сделать отдельными для всех пользователей? Чтобы выбор одного не перемешивался с выбором другого, не записывать каждую переменную в бд? или как?

aiogram - FSM. telebot - register_next_step_handler

Предоставьте хотя бы минимальный пример кода, чтобы было понятно в чём у Вас проблема. Можете и на старой библиотеке telebot, принцип будет ясен и так.
